# How do I leverage Bitlocker cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, bitlocker

[This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj647767.aspx) hints at being able to unlock a bitlocked drive using:

```
Unlock-BitLocker -MountPoint -Password
```

However, I know diddly squat about Powershell and how to use the Powershell cmdlets to do what I want to do.

So, how do I do use the above to do something like the following?

```
Unlock-BitLocker -MountPoint D:\ -Password "password"
```

Currently about as much as I know how to do is start Powershell and that's it.  I don't want to learn masses of Powershell to get to the point where I can do this. All that I need to know in enough to know how I can execute the commands that are pointed out in the first link.

So far in the powershell prompt if I past in:

```
Unlock-BitLocker -MountPoint D:\ -Password "password"
```

I get the following error:

```
The term 'Unlock-BitLocker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Chec
k the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:17
+ Unlock-BitLocker <<<<  -MountPoint D:\ -Password "password"
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Unlock-BitLocker:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

This is most likely because I don't have any clue about how the commands on the initially linked page work in a powershell context.

This is so that I can answer my own question here:

https://superuser.com/questions/437713/bitlocker-and-scheduled-task-powershell-script-to-unlock-non-system-drive

Comment: What operating system are your using? The Technet article applies to  Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.

Comment: This is in Windows 7 x64 sp1.  Yes, this has only just recently been changed to reflect the upcoming release/release of those platforms.

Comment: Windows Server 2008 is not upcoming. I'm pretty sure the cmdlets existed on Server since 2008 but are only now becoming available on desktop in Windows 8. But that's just an assumption based on that article

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831713.aspx) (section "Practical applications") the *BitLocker Drive Encryption Tools* are a new addition to the [Remote Server Administration Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28972) and according to [this article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2202.remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-vista-windows-7-windows-8-windows-server-2008-windows-server-2008-r2-and-windows-server-2012-dsforum2wiki.aspx) are not available on Windows 7 (see support matrix at the bottom of the page).